# jq returning null as string if the json is empty

Tags: bash, jq

I'm running this command do get a value from the json;

`addr=$(./xuez-cli getnetworkinfo | jq -r '.localaddresses[0].address')`

and it works just fine.

BUT if this `.localaddresses[0].address` part empty or doesn't even exist, jq sets the `addr` variable as `null` like this; `addr=null`

and I want to check if the json is empty/null and run some other command instead of parsing it as `null` string.

I couldn't find a way to work this around. How can I do this?

Comment: Add output of `./xuez-cli getnetworkinfo` to your question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First, a note: There's nothing inherently wrong with `addr=null`; you can just test for it:

```
if [[ $addr = null ]]; then ...code here...; fi
```

The rest of this answer pretends the above were untrue. :)

---

There are two practices that are notable as improving ease of error handling for this case:

- Using `set -o pipefail` will detect whether any part -- not just the last component -- of a shell pipeline fails.
- Using `jq -e` will cause `jq`'s exit status to reflect whether it returned content that was either false or null.

---

Thus:

```
set -o pipefail
if addr=$(./xuez-cli getnetworkinfo | jq -er '.localaddresses[0].address'); then
  : "address retrieved successfully; this message is not logged unless set -x is active"
else
  echo "Running other logic here"
fi
```

...goes to `Running other logic here` if *either* `jq` fails (and `-e` specifies that `false` and `null` shall be treated as failures), *or* if `xuez-cli` reports an unsuccessful exit status.

Comment: My understanding is that if `address` is `"null"` instead of `null` then `if [[ $addr = null ]];` can cause problems.

Comment: @searchstar, that's only true if it's `'"null"'`. That is to say, only literal quotes -- not syntactic ones -- count for the comparison; and when you say `value="null"`, the outer quotes are syntactic. In particular, jq emits a null as just `null` -- no literal quotes present -- and in `value="$(jq ...)"`, the `"`s are syntactic. Now, if someone put the _string_ `"null"` inside a JSON value that'll happen, but it would need to be deliberately a string instead of a null literal, and in that case the comparison being false is correct (the JSON string `"null"` _isn't_ identical to JSON `null`).

Comment: However, if `address` is `"null"` then if `[[ $addr = null ]]; ` is actually true. We can quickly verify it: `addr=$(echo "{\"a\": \"null\"}" | jq -r ".a"); if [[ $addr = null ]]; then echo yes; fi`. It prints "yes". However, I think it shouldn't, because as you mentioned, the JSON string `"null"` isn't identical to JSON `null`.

Comment: @searchstar That's because you used the `-r` argument to jq, which causes strings to have only their raw value emitted while not changing how anything else is serialized. Take it out if you want those values to be distinguishable. The bash is still fine; what you just demonstrated is a jq usage problem.

Answer (score 84):

Something useful I found for shell scripts was:

```
jq '.foo // empty'
```

Which returns the match if successful, and the empty string if unsuccessful. So in bash I use:

```
addr=$(./xuez-cli getnetworkinfo | jq -r '.localaddresses[0].address // empty')

if [[ ! -z "$addr" ]]; then
    # do something
fi
```

Ref: https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/354#issuecomment-43147898
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/451479/jq-print-for-null-values

Comment: I think this should be the appropriate correct answer as It reflects the question for an empty string a lot better so please @Tolgahan Bozkurt approve this answer as the correct one!

Comment: Nice ;-) Using it with '$(...)' may be inaccurate though, when the raw value have newlines at the end, they will be truncated.